# For loop uses a recursive call's output as parameter

Tags: python, recursion

Currently going through Mark Lutz - Learning Python 5e and there is a permutation function which I cannot come to grips with and was hoping for some guidance.

```
def permute1(seq):
    if not seq:
        return [seq]
    else:
        res = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            for x in permute1(rest):
                res.append(seq[i:i+1] + x)
        return res

seq = (1,2,3)
permute1(seq)
```

1. Which values are being used for `x`. Is it from the previous `permute1()` call?
2. Why is `res` at the top of the `else:` statement remain empty throughout the process? Is it a mutable vs immutable issue? To which variable is the `for` loop actually appending its output to?
3. Is the procedure of emptying out a sequence before rebuilding it inside a `for` loop a common design pattern that I can look up elsewhere?

Here is perhaps a more helpful version of the `permute1()` with all the variables being printed out.

```
def permute1(seq):
    if not seq:
        return [seq]
    else:
        res = []
        print('at the top seq = {} res = {},'.format(seq, res))
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            print('recursive call seq = {}, rest = {}, i = {}'.format(seq, rest, i))
            for x in permute1(rest):
                print('inside x = {}, rest = {}, seq = {}'.format(x, rest, seq))
                res.append(seq[i:i+1] + x)
        print('seq = {}; res = {}'.format(seq,res))
        return res

seq = (1,2,3)
permute1(seq)
```

Comment: Where did `rest` come from in the first example? Nothing in the function defines that name.

Comment: In the second example you set `rest`, but that's missing from the first.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Will try to amend it quickly.

Comment: `res` doesn't remain empty. It is being appended to in the `for` loop. You need to read through **all** the output, because it only appears to remain empty on the first series of recursive calls, for your example there's `seq = (3,); res = [(3,)]` and `seq = (2,); res = [(2,)]` and `seq = (2, 3); res = [(2, 3), (3, 2)]`, and more.

Comment: This just simply picks one element at a time from the sequence being passed in and passes the remaining down into a recursive call. `rest` is just the rest of the sequence without the one element. Each of the results of the recursive call is being stored in `res`. BTW: you don't need the `else:` block because the `if` block returns. I find code easier to read without unnecessary indentation.

Comment: thanks for editing the post. I do see res populated at the very end of the output but empty while it is running in the "at the top"-print-statement; do not really understand why that is. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Recursive calls can be confusing at first. You should add a `level` argument to the function, that starts with `level=0`. Then alter the recursive call to `permute1(rest, level + 1)` and add `'  ' * level,` to the start of all your `print()` calls. That way you get to see where you are at with recursive calls. It's *just another function call*, like you call `print()` in your code here, there is nothing otherwise special about it.

Comment: `res` is empty because nothing appends to it until the recursive function calls start returning..

Comment: Also, why not print in the `if not seq` part?

Comment: yes - that makes sense; the if statement would work as a 'catch all' and then carry on running. thanks, @AChampion

Comment: A level-counter is solid advice - the print statements will be far more helpful. Did not print in the 'if not seq:' statement because intuitively knew when it was being hit; nevertheless inconsistent. thanks for the help, @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive function call is *just another function call*, there is nothing special about such calls, really. You call a function, and when it returns, you use the result of that call.

With recursion, what happens is that there is a *stack* of calls, one calling another calling another until eventually a function *returns a result*, and thus the first, outer calls may have to wait a while before it can continue with the result given.

In your example, `permute1()` always returns a list (`return [seq]` at the top, or `return res` further down), so `for x in ...` loops over that result (once the recursive call returns) and uses each tuple in the result to prepend a single-element tuple to it (`res[i:i + 1]` slices a tuple to contain just a single element, the one at index `i`).

When you call the function with an empty tuple, the function return immediately:

```
>>> permute1(())
[()]
```

This is the one stage where there is no recursive call, and that's important! It's how recursion ends!

The other block creates a new list of elements from `seq`, using `rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]`. That's a tuple with *one* element removed, that at index `i`:

```
>>> seq
(1, 2, 3)
>>> seq[:1] + seq[2:]  # if i is 1, then..
(1, 3)
```

If you call `permute1()` with a *single element tuple*, then `for i in range(len(seq))` loops just once, with `i = 0`. That means that `res` is set to an empty tuple (a tuple of length one with 1 element removed is an empty tuple), and thus there is a single `permute1(())` call made. We saw above that that just returns `[()]`, and you end up with `seq[i:i+1] + x` added to `res`, and the function returns.

So a call with a single element in it makes *one* recursive call, and returns a list with a single tuple, essentially the same as what you started with:

```
>>> permute1((1,))
[(1,)]
```

With 2 elements, the loop iterates twice, calls `permute1()` twice with a single element tuple, which does the above. Those two calls each result in a list with 1 element, so you end up with `res` with two new tuples, the two orderings of the input elements:

```
>>> permute1((1,))
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

You can extrapolate from there how 3 elements works.

It can help to **indent** print information, by passing along level information:

```
def permute1(seq, level=0):
    indent = '    ' * level
    p = lambda msg, *args: print(indent + msg.format(*args))
    p('permute1({}, {}) called', seq, level)
    if not seq:
        p('- end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]')
        return [seq]
    else:
        p('- Looping {} times over {}', len(seq), seq)
        res = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            p('| Loop #{}, rest is: {}, seq[i] is {}, making recursive call', i + 1, rest, seq[i])
            for x in permute1(rest, level + 1):
                p(' + processing 1 result from recursive call, {}', x)
                res.append(seq[i:i+1] + x)
                p(' + res appended to, now {}', res)
            p('\ Loop #{} complete, res is: {}', i + 1, res)
        p('Function done, returning {}', res)
        return res
```

The `p` lambda prints the message with `level` times 4 spaces in front; the deeper the recursion, the more the call is indented.

That's a bit more verbose, but now you can see at what level things happen:

```
>>> permute1(seq)
permute1((1, 2, 3), 0) called
- Looping 3 times over (1, 2, 3)
| Loop #1, rest is: (2, 3), seq[i] is 1, making recursive call
    permute1((2, 3), 1) called
    - Looping 2 times over (2, 3)
    | Loop #1, rest is: (3,), seq[i] is 2, making recursive call
        permute1((3,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (3,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 3, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(3,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(3,)]
        Function done, returning [(3,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (3,)
     + res appended to, now [(2, 3)]
    \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(2, 3)]
    | Loop #2, rest is: (2,), seq[i] is 3, making recursive call
        permute1((2,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (2,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 2, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(2,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(2,)]
        Function done, returning [(2,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (2,)
     + res appended to, now [(2, 3), (3, 2)]
    \ Loop #2 complete, res is: [(2, 3), (3, 2)]
    Function done, returning [(2, 3), (3, 2)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (2, 3)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (3, 2)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2)]
\ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2)]
| Loop #2, rest is: (1, 3), seq[i] is 2, making recursive call
    permute1((1, 3), 1) called
    - Looping 2 times over (1, 3)
    | Loop #1, rest is: (3,), seq[i] is 1, making recursive call
        permute1((3,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (3,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 3, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(3,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(3,)]
        Function done, returning [(3,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (3,)
     + res appended to, now [(1, 3)]
    \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(1, 3)]
    | Loop #2, rest is: (1,), seq[i] is 3, making recursive call
        permute1((1,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (1,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 1, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(1,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(1,)]
        Function done, returning [(1,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (1,)
     + res appended to, now [(1, 3), (3, 1)]
    \ Loop #2 complete, res is: [(1, 3), (3, 1)]
    Function done, returning [(1, 3), (3, 1)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (1, 3)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (3, 1)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1)]
\ Loop #2 complete, res is: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1)]
| Loop #3, rest is: (1, 2), seq[i] is 3, making recursive call
    permute1((1, 2), 1) called
    - Looping 2 times over (1, 2)
    | Loop #1, rest is: (2,), seq[i] is 1, making recursive call
        permute1((2,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (2,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 2, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(2,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(2,)]
        Function done, returning [(2,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (2,)
     + res appended to, now [(1, 2)]
    \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(1, 2)]
    | Loop #2, rest is: (1,), seq[i] is 2, making recursive call
        permute1((1,), 2) called
        - Looping 1 times over (1,)
        | Loop #1, rest is: (), seq[i] is 1, making recursive call
            permute1((), 3) called
            - end stage, seq is empty, returning [(),]
         + processing 1 result from recursive call, ()
         + res appended to, now [(1,)]
        \ Loop #1 complete, res is: [(1,)]
        Function done, returning [(1,)]
     + processing 1 result from recursive call, (1,)
     + res appended to, now [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
    \ Loop #2 complete, res is: [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
    Function done, returning [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (1, 2)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2)]
 + processing 1 result from recursive call, (2, 1)
 + res appended to, now [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
\ Loop #3 complete, res is: [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
Function done, returning [(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
```